Why do I feel betrayed?
I know this sounds wrong. Currently, I feel heavily discouraged in life. I’ve been on my deen; I’ve been doing my best to stay away from sin. I had conversations with Allah, and I believe he has shown me signs in answering a dua of mine. Yesterday I believe I got a sign that a dua I’ve been making for a long time will not be answered. This has happened before, and I accepted it. However, this time I believe Allah gave me signs that he would answer this one, so when I got this answer that it will not happen, I felt really upset and felt like, What’s the point? I know Allah knows best and wants the best for me, but this is not the first time this has happened, and I’m trying to be more grateful and try to become better, but this made me very upset, and I don’t know what to do.
